# To use sessions or db queries when doing check-up on every page?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, optimization

I have application that has to check multiple data from user table, in order to create page.

Not just id and password, but other data as well, about 7 parts of information at this moment.

This check-up is done on every page.

Do I load all this data in session, and check it from there, or do I fire query on every page request? Needless to say, there are also other queries going on.

What's better practice, regarding optimization?

Comment: To expand on this question, wouldn't it be better to request the user data at each request instead of checking session? If a mod/admin deletes a user, how will the user get kicked of the app? As long as the session stays active, the user will be logged in in the app. Also what about permissions? Again, if a mod/admin edits a user's permissions, shouldn't these also be requested at each request so that the change applies immediately? Storing the user info in session once at log-in, and then checking the session for user data for the continuing requests seems dangerous, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the data once from the database and store it in a Session Variable. I generally put my user_id, username, email, user firstname & access_levels in a session when the user first logs in, Then I can call them anywhere in my application whilst the user is logged in.

Do not store the password in the session as it would not be required.

You an also create a variable called logged_in and set it to true or false to test against, (i.e: Show the "Account menu if the user is logged in, else show "Register" Menu).

---

[Update]

Here is a link to the Pro's/Con's of MySQL caching.
[Scroll down to the bottom before the comments.](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/)

It kinda depends on your site, for a small site query  caching would be fine, but if you wanted to develop more scalable applications, You have to keep speed in mind.

---

How to tell is mysql query cache is enabled: [[LINK](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/tell-if-mysql-query-cache-enabled/)]

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will cache the query if it's exactly the same as last time, so getting the user information via MySQL is fine. And especially so if you are getting everything via the primary key which is very fast.

Comment: Is query cache default on on most hostings, or it has to be turned on?

Comment: Go into phpmyadmin > run sql query> paste this > " show variables like 'query_cache_size'; ", It will show the size of your query cache, Mine is turned off by default on localhost.

Comment: It seems query cache can't handle prepared statements with placeholders, so I can't use this way of caching

Comment: @Marko Nothing can cache a statement with a placeholder for the simpler reason that there is nothing to cache - the placeholder means it doesn't have the data yet. How is it supposed to cache it? You could cache the query plan, but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trips to database are slower than accessing sessions. You should definitely use sessions. Just don't forget that if this data changed in a database, it should also be changed in the current session.

Comment: Internally sessions are files on disk. I'm not convinced opening, parsing, and reading a file is faster than having a local MySQL server retrieve the result from its cache. And especially once you consider how much overheard (extra code) he's going to have to deal with to make this work.

Comment: This really depends on how many queries he sends to the database. It's not the transfer of data that is painful performance wise. It's the connection (unless he uses persistent, which is a no no in my book). Also do not forget that php sessions are handled internally, so they are pretty fast. In addition to that, add memcached session handler and it's the fastest way possible. Anyway, got an interest in this - gonna do some benchmarking this weekend :)

P.S. Never seen a web application that always check user data in a database instead of using sessions.

Comment: A local MySQL connection is very fast, faster than opening and reading a file. With a remote database (not on the same machine) you are correct. PS. If you have never seen a web app that doesn't use sessions you have not been looking.

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't change too much you could cache it to a file ... or cache it to memory using something like memcache.

Then you can include it via this file and set some theshholds on when to fetch from db or just include.

Comment: MySQL has a built in cache: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html you don't need to double cache this. At least not till you get WAY larger.

Comment: We do not know the scale of his application, so offering my experienced advice.

Comment: Application is to be launched, so now it's not scaled, and will not be at the beginning, but my position is to do it for scale

Comment: For the several large scale sites I operate, we use memcached to good effect (along with other tools), but if you're resources are limited initially... simply caching content to a file does help. It all depends on how expensive (time consuming) you're query is. There are other options too - MongoDB, CouchDB etc are all used for highly available sites.

Comment: Are there any drawback on how many files I can have? For example, for 10000 users, there's 10000 files. Does this matter, or not?

Comment: @Marko you are reaching the land of premature optimization. You don't know what will actually be slow in your app. I suggest first finding the slow part, and only then fixing it. You may end up being surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Your question uses "check" - do you mean that you have to validate data on every page request? If so, you probably can't avoid going to the database.

If all you need to do is store data that doesn't change between pages for the same user, you should use sessions. Be sure to read the white paper "PHP is Not Java" on the zend.com website first!

Comment: I have to read data in order to create page, and that data randomly changes, but it can be changed, so I need to check it all the time.

Comment: Yeah, then you have to go to the database every page. Is this currently a measurable performance problem?

Comment: No at this time, since application is yet to be launched, and this won't be an issue at the beggining of usage, but since coding is on it's way, I feel it's better to do it right one time, and not to worry later on